# C# dynamic keyword and thread safety

Tags: c#, dynamic, thread-safety, zeromq

EDIT heres the github page if people want to have a look
https://github.com/brandongrossutti/EventStore

I am having a very odd issue and cant quite figure the root cause.
I have a zeromq subscriber on its own thread.
When it gets a message it calls a delegate and then goes into a messagehandler which eventually gets to this dynamic call

```
    private void OnEvent(IEvent @event, bool isNew)
    {
        string eventName = "On" + @event.GetType().Name.Replace("Event", "");
        dynamic inheritingClass = this;
        MethodInfo method = inheritingClass.GetType().GetMethod(eventName);
        method.Invoke(inheritingClass, new object[] { @event });
        if (isNew)_uncommitedEvents.Add(@event);
    }
```

it dies on the invoke and the call stack and exception dont show a thing.
If i step through slowly, it seems to work just fine.  Very confused.

thanks in advance

EDIT:

heres the badly written code for the thread that starts the subscriber

```
    private readonly IHandlerResolver _resolver;
    private readonly Thread _subscriberThread;

    public MessageSubscriber(OnTheWireBusConfiguration configuration, IHandlerResolver resolver)
    {
        _resolver = resolver;

        _subscriberThread = new Thread(RecieveMessages);
        _subscriberThread.Start(new object[] { configuration, resolver, new Action<Message>(ProcessMessage) });
    }

    private static void RecieveMessages(object o)
    {
        object[] obj = o as object[];
        OnTheWireBusConfiguration configuration = (OnTheWireBusConfiguration)obj[0];
        IHandlerResolver resolver = (IHandlerResolver)obj[1];
        Action<Message> handlerDelegate = (Action<Message>) obj[2];
        using (var context = new Context(configuration.MaxThreads))
        {
            using (Socket subscriber = context.Socket(SocketType.SUB))
            {
                subscriber.Subscribe("", Encoding.Unicode);
                subscriber.Connect("tcp://localhost:5565");

                while (true)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = subscriber.Recv();
                    Message message = (Message) configuration.Deserialize(buffer);
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                    handlerDelegate(message);
                    //resolver.ExecuteHandler(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void ProcessMessage(Message message)
    {
       _resolver.ExecuteHandler(message);
    }
```

EDIT#2
Call Stack

> GHI.EventRepository.dll!GHI.EventRepository.AggregateRoot.OnEvent(GHI.EventRepository.IEvent event, bool isNew) Line 39 C#
>       GHI.EventRepository.dll!GHI.EventRepository.AggregateRoot.OnEvent(GHI.EventRepository.IEvent event) Line 29 + 0x12 bytes    C#
>       GHI.TestDomain.dll!GHI.TestDomain.Model.TestAggregateRoot.TestAggregateRoot(System.Guid id) Line 15 + 0x59 bytes    C#
>       GHI.TestDomain.dll!GHI.TestDomain.Handlers.CreateNewTestAggregateRootCommandHandler.HandleMessage(GHI.TestDomain.Messages.CreateNewTestAggregateRootCommand message) Line 20 + 0x62 bytes   C#
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       GHI.Bus.dll!GHI.Bus.HandlerResolver.ExecuteHandler(GHI.Bus.Message message) Line 40 + 0x95 bytes    C#
>       GHI.Bus.ZeroMQ.dll!GHI.Bus.ZeroMQ.MessageSubscriber.ProcessMessage(GHI.Bus.Message message) Line 48 + 0x38 bytes    C#
>       GHI.Bus.ZeroMQ.dll!GHI.Bus.ZeroMQ.MessageSubscriber.RecieveMessages(object o) Line 39 + 0x13 bytes  C#
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(object userData) + 0x173 bytes
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xeb bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x3b bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(object obj) + 0x5d bytes 
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Appdomain Transition]
>       [Native to Managed Transition]

I can pop this onto Github if easier

EDIT #4
Thanks for everyones help, glad i could remove the dynamic keyword from that bit of code.
Dynamic was not the issue it was my locking way up the stack, thank you again, I have upvoted thos that mentioned dynamic issue and will accept the answer below

Comment: "call stack and exception dont show a thing"? What do they show, then?

Comment: Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

Comment: 'It dies.' Could you give us the results of the autopsy?

Comment: upon looking closer its dying at MethodInfo method = inheritingClass.GetType().GetMethod(eventName);

Comment: You can wrap it into try-catch block and then write an exception to console/log file/show a messagebox. Most probable you have a null reference but i'm not sure without any debug information. How can you be sure it dies on this line?

Comment: the exception im getting throws this "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack"

Comment: Im not super confident in my zeromq subscriber thread is calling back correctly

Comment: Oh sorry, you've posted it already, i missed it. Are you in debug or release build? Do you use mixed mode? It could help to see all the stacktrace for both managed and native calls

Comment: debug, any cpu on a x64 system using zeromq's 64 build

Comment: Why are you using dynamic at all?  If you are going to use reflection, just calling GetType will do without the dynamic.

Comment: GetType() will not get the actual type that is inheriting that class

Comment: +1 @ChrisShain's comment: There's no point in using `dynamic` if you're going to `GetType()` with `Invoke` anyway...

Comment: I stand corrected you guys are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with zeromq, but looking at your `OnEvent` method, I don't see `dynamic` as necessary. What happens when you don't use `dynamic`, and replace the method with this?

```
private void OnEvent(IEvent @event, bool isNew)
{
    string eventName = "On" + @event.GetType().Name.Replace("Event", "");
    MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod(eventName);
    method.Invoke(this, new object[] { @event });
    if (isNew)_uncommitedEvents.Add(@event);
}
```

If there's no change to the behavior, then the problem may be elsewhere.

(Probably want to add a `if(method != null)` around the Invoke, unless you're absolutely sure it'll be there all the time.)

Comment: GetType() will not get the actual type that is inheriting that class, thus the reason for the dynamic call, the On..... method is only present on the class that is inheriting from there

Comment: Yes it will. I think you're confusing `foo.GetType()` with `typeof(Foo)`. `@event.GetType()` isn't returning `IEvent`, it's returning the implementing class; the call to `this.GetType()` will work the same way.

Comment: so dynamic is not the issue, all of my other tests pass fine with that change. but still getting exception on invoke